# Cannot update label with new date inside tableview cell with datepicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, datepicker

I have a tableview inside of a view controller.  My plan is that inside my tableview cell is a label and when the user taps the tableview cell that a UIAlertView ActionSheet would appear with a datepicker inside.  After much frustration, I ended up using a repo on github called [LGAlertView](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGAlertView).  This seemed like an excellent choice!  It's beautiful and seems to work smoothly.  It has a datepicker inside of it.  However it only works once and then it cannot update my label again.  Meaning, I can set the date the first time I select the cell and it updates my label in my cell perfectly, but if I were to select the cell again and choose a date, it does not update my label.

A little more info:

My label has a tag in storyboards of 100.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        datePicker = [UIDatePicker new];
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, self.view.frame.size.width, 110.f);
        [[[LGAlertView alloc] initWithViewAndTitle:@"What Day Did You Get Married"
                                           message:@"Tap Done When Finished"
                                             style:LGAlertViewStyleActionSheet
                                              view:datePicker
                                      buttonTitles:@[@"Done"]
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     actionHandler:^(LGAlertView *alertView, NSString *title, NSUInteger index){
                                         selectedDate = datePicker.date;
                                         NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                                         df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
                                         UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AnniversaryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                                         UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:100];
                                         dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Married Since: %@",[df stringFromDate:selectedDate]];
                                         [cell setSelected:NO];

                                         NSLog(@"actionHandler, %@, %lu", title, (long unsigned)index);
                                     }
                                     cancelHandler:^(LGAlertView *alertView) {
                                         NSLog(@"cancelHandler");
                                     }
                                destructiveHandler:^(LGAlertView *alertView)
                                {
                                    NSLog(@"destructiveHandler");
                                }]
         showAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AnniversaryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```